# Getting error when instantiating a trait within a class (method became private)

Tags: scala, access-modifiers, anonymous-inner-class

In the following code, I'm trying to instantiate the trait A with the `Decorator` class and add a method `p` to it so I can get another object A but with a `p` method:

```
trait A {
  def x: Int
}

case class Decorator(a: A) {
  def withPrint: A = new A {
    val x = 100
    def p: Unit = println(x)
  }
}

val a = new A {val x = 100}

val d = Decorator(a).withPrint
```

But when I try to call `d.p` it gives error

> value p is not a member of A$A54.this.A

Also then I print the declared methods in `d` I see `p` is **private**!

```
d.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.foreach(println)

# public int stringsimilarity.A$A55$A$A55$Decorator$$anon$2.x()
# private void stringsimilarity.A$A55$A$A55$Decorator$$anon$2.p()
```

Could anyone explain why this happens? Any help will be really appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why `def p` should be public. It's a method that you defined in a local anonymous class that implements trait `A`. The trait `A` declares only public method `x`, and nothing else. Therefore, the only scope where you have access to `p` is inside of the initializer of the `new A { ... }`, so `private` seems appropriate for that.

If you want to expose the method `p`, you can either add it to `A` (then you have to implement it there, and then you also don't need the `withPrint` method at all), or mix in an additional trait that guarantees the presence of method `p`. For example:

```
trait A {
  def x: Int
}

trait Print {
  def p: Unit
}

case class Decorator(a: A) {
  def withPrint: A with Print = new A with Print {
    val x = 100
    def p: Unit = println(x)
  }
}

val a = new A { val x = 100 }

val d = Decorator(a).withPrint

d.p
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey! Using mixin makes a lot more sense, you are the man!

Comment: Does it work if we add the `def p: Unit` abstract method directly in `trait A` by removing the `trait Print`completely and also the `with Print` mixin in `withPrint` method.? It is working if we add the `implemented method p` in trait A but not with abstract method..can you please clarify this Andrey Tyukin?

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM If we add `def p: Unit` to `trait A`, then we have to provide it by the time we instantiate `val a = new A { ... }`, that is, we either have to include it in `trait A { ... }` right from the beginning, or add it to each `new A { ... }`. In both cases, `withPrint` method as such becomes useless. So, if you wanted to keep `withPrint` that does something halfway-meaningful, I don't see how to avoid mixing in or refining the return type.